# Not able to integrate push plugin in phonegap for OS

Tags: cordova

I'm developing phonegap application that uses push plugin. But I'm getting an error message in the following line while adding reference in the config.xml.

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin"/>
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin"/>` try this

```
<plugin name="PushPlugin" value="com.plugin.gcm.PushPlugin" />
```

And check com.plugin.gcm.pushplugin in java src folder

Comment: Hi, but i'm working in iOS platform and I'm using X Code

Comment: Oh i am sorry i will check and tell

Comment: @varghesekutty u have "com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" in  your src folder ?

Comment: Yes i have, com.xxx.xxxx.plugins.PushPlugin

Comment: @varghesekutty once again read this flow https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

Comment: @red_skull there is nothing mentioned about this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44878/discussion-between-varghesekutty-and-red-skull)